# best way to have a central database and remote can be portable

Tags: database, delphi

I´m trying to do a system that has a central database in the office and if necessary I work in a copy of the database out of the office and when i return i update the client(s) record.

I have for each client a master table dataset client========>Local places of this client===> Equipment====>Report(variables).

so when I return I have to Update the master table Insert or update the other dependent tables.

```
client  (Edit)
Local places (Edit or Insert or Delete)
Equipment (Edit or Insert or Delete)
Report(variables)(Edit or Insert or Delete)
```

Thank´s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently use Asta (TAstaClientDataset) to suitcase my data (in office / off office). astatech.com has demo and tutoriels to show (suitcase.dpr). Works nice and fast for any database system.

Comment: But they only have for delphi 7?

Comment: Also for Delphi 2009  - and 2010. Ask the author for D2010.

Answer (score 1):

The `TClientDataset` component provided with Delphi should provide the capabilities you need for that.  Check the documentation for TClientDataset, especially the parts about using the "briefcase model" for temporary local storage of data.  It's almost exactly what you're describing.

Comment: yes i need something like that  i will have a go i found something in http://www.drbob42.com/  or http://www.podgoretsky.com/ftp/docs/Delphi/D5/dg/one2tier.html. but if some one has a source it will be welcome  . thank´s
And what tipe of database ?
SQL or Firebird?
Thanks

Comment: @re TClientDataset can be used with any database for which a provider is available. On the client-side you don't need a database as TClientDataset supports storing changes to disk.

Comment: thank´s but really i didn't found a good way to make my new aplicacion
and if i use firebird and work with TTable and BatchMove?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mason's suggestion (the TClientDataset) which is a very good idea, you could consider using NexusDB, I'm pretty sure it supports something called Replication, which basically involves syncing changes between multiple (local+ remote, or two offices with their own databases) databases.

Answer (score 0):

So the simple way to solve my problem is to delete and append new field´s each time i want to update my server database!

something like this

```
Sub_TRelFinal.Post;
end;
  ADOTable_casa_sub_1.First;
Sub_TRelFinal_1.DisableControls;
DBGridEh4.SelectedRows.SelectAll;
DBGridEh4.SelectedRows.Delete;
 while not ADOTable_casa_sub_1.Eof do begin
begin
 Sub_TRelFinal_1.enableControls;
 Sub_TRelFinal_1.append;
```

because my master record is the index of my image  folder  \picture\123..............

or is there a simples way?

Thank´s